# Composer install on windows stops at patching

Tags: windows, drupal, composer-php, drupal-8

Does anyone know why this keeps happening at "composer install" ?
and how to fix this ?

```
C:\Users\1337\Desktop\wafasalaf>composer install
Gathering patches from patch file.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: Support for Composer 1 is deprecated and some packages will not be available. You should upgrade to Composer 2. See https://blog.packagist.com/deprecating-composer-1-support/
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 152 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
Gathering patches from patch file.
Gathering patches for dependencies. This might take a minute.
  - Installing drupal/core (8.9.16): Loading from cache
  - Applying patches for drupal/core
    modules/patches/block-remove-logger-warning.patch (Remove not found blocks warning.)
   Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch modules/patches/block-remove-logger-warning.patch


  [Exception]
  Cannot apply patch Remove not found blocks warning. (modules/patches/block-remove-logger-warning.patch)!


update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Comment: `Could not apply patch!` - have you checked whether the patches are still valid, that they can still be applied to the code you try to use?

Comment: They are all valid, the problem that i found now, is that i don't have patch command on my windows pc, and i don't know how to get it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is resolved, I had a problem on windows where Patch was not identified.

All I had to do is put the path link of the patch.exe in my system environments (if you have git for windows it's already installed & you'll find it in "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin").